# Webview Flickering Android 10: "tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw" Multiple WebViews inside my app

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chromium

Since one or two weeks some ads inside my app wont show up and would just flicker!
Its random when this happens, and it flickers continuously

I have banner ads and video ads in my app and thats the way i call them:

```
holder.wv.setInitialScale(1);
holder.wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); //i call that on banner ads, stackoverflow fix
holder.wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
holder.wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 0, 0, 0)); //stackoverflow fix
holder.wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
holder.wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
holder.wv.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
holder.wv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
//loadurl etc
```

I already googled a lot and found out that the hardware acceleration might be problem so I am turning it off for the banner ads but for my video ads i cant because otherwise they wouldnt work

My ads are integrated in a Recyclerview that loads a CardView with the Webview inside. I have 4-5 on each site but there were no problems with the amount of ads, never. There must be kind of issue with the Webview or the Chrome Driver itself? Thats what came up when I searched for my problem

Does anyone encountered this problem?

E/chromium: [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(793)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw

Answer (score 2):

I resetted the Android System Webview in Settings -> Apps and now the flickering is gone!

84.0.4147.111 was the latest version and stock version of my Galaxy S10 80.0.3987.99 works now!

Hope this gets fixed:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1005077

Answer (score 0):

##### Same Error in Cordova Android App - Different Reason and Solution(?)

I am assuming it's possible (likely) that I got this error for entirely different reasons than the OP but am sharing here because the error message was the same for my case (and no other SO article seems to exist for this, yet).

###### TLDR: My Solution

Remove the android platform via `cordova platform rm android` (*annoying yes I know*) and re-add it `cordova platform add android`. Rebuilt it with cordova and re-ran it on my device and the error was gone.

###### Background

I was working on an Android Cordova project and it had been building and running fine all day. I had been spending time trying to get the splash screen to work (*thanks to the semi-recent, annoying, [splash screen changes](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions) Android made*) so I was editing and moving files in the /res/android folder, /node_modules folders, etc. Anyhow after I FINALLY got the splash screen working I ran into a NEW issue where my app would instantly crash when I would tap on any item using cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to open a web URL and in my Android Studio logs I saw a bunch of this error (same as the OP):

`E/chromium: [ERROR:tile_manager.cc(822)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw`

After getting the issue resolved (see Solution above) my guess is that some file/folder changes I had made during my splash screen work made something in the Android build wonky and that's what would causing my app to crash and get this error. Obviously I never found the specific file/issue but the solution works for now. If anyone ever learns more about this error and finds a way to resolve w/out having to remove/re-add the android platform to the app please do chime in!

##### Setup/Reference

- Cordova (CLI) 11.1.0
- Cordova-Android@11.0.0
- Windows 10x64
- Device: LGE Nexus 5 (old I know)
- Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 2 Build #AI-221.6008.13.221.9619390